# API response is array of 15 items but I can only get the first item to display with v-for

Tags: rest, vuejs3, laravel-9, vue-composition-api, quasar-framework

I've just started building a web app with Quasar V2 for the frontend and Laravel 9 for the API. The data from my GET request is coming back like this:

[image: console log of response]

I'm then putting the response into a variable -

```
const memorials = ref([]);
api
  .get("http://localhost:8000/api/researcher-resources/memorials")
  .then((response) => {
    memorials.value = response.data;
    console.log(memorials.value);
  })
```

and trying to output the variable in a q-list -

```
<q-list>
        <q-item
          v-for="(memorial, key, index) in memorials"
          :key="memorial[index].id"
        >
          <q-item-section>
            <q-item-label
              >{{ index }} - {{ key }} -
              {{ memorial[index].name }}</q-item-label
            >
            <q-item-label caption>{{
              memorial[index].conflict.name
            }}</q-item-label>
          </q-item-section>

          <q-item-section side top>
            <q-badge color="teal" :label="memorial[index].noOfPersonnel" />
          </q-item-section>
        </q-item>
      </q-list>
```

All I'm getting is the first item in the response but the data is definitely there. If I change the index to a number between 0 and 15 it will show the relevant line of the response. Can anyone give me any pointers as to where I'm going wrong?

I tried flattening the array from the Laravel end, same issue and most of the other things I tried caused errors with Quasar not getting a value for the different attributes.

Comment: What is that `key` doing there in the `v-for` If `memorials` is an array, the correct syntax is `v-for = "(memorial, index) in memorials"` And you probably want to access `memorials[index]` instead of `memorial[index]`. And why do you even access the properties by index, if `memoral` is already your object. You can just use `memorial.name`

Comment: @derpirscher The `key` was just something else I was trying after looking at the Vue 3 docs. `memorials[index]` causes an error of `undefined reading 'name'` and just using `memorial.name` etc causes the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you take a read of the v-for documentation [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#v-for)

there's no need to use [index] anywhere in that code as the item is already in an iterative list and will only access the current memorial.

the below code should work (note: have remove the key as your comment above states it was only added to try out something)

```html
<template>
    <q-list>
        <q-item
            v-for="(memorial, index) in memorials"
            :key="index"
        >
            <q-item-section>
                <q-item-label>
                    {{ index }} - {{ memorial.name }}
                </q-item-label>
                <q-item-label caption>
                    {{ memorial.conflict.name }}
                </q-item-label>
            </q-item-section>

            <q-item-section
                side
                top
            >
                <q-badge
                    color="teal"
                    :label="memorial.noOfPersonnel"
                />
            </q-item-section>
        </q-item>
    </q-list>
</template>
```

Comment: many thanks for your answer but I stuck with using the `key` and now have it working as it should. `<q-item v-for="(memorial, key) in memorials.data" :key="key">` ie `memorials.data` and accessing by `{{ memorial.name }}`. I did already try the way you suggested but it didn't work. Think it's because 'data' is an array of objects.

Comment: the easiest thing to do then is just assign memorials like so memorials.value = response.data.data; removes the need to have .data added whenever you want to use the array